# Stylize sibling elements with additive transforms

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to achieve the following without having to declare all the `nth-of-type(x)`:

```css
li:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
li:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: scale(0.81);
}
li:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: scale(0.729);
}
li:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: scale(0.6561);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LI 1</li>
  <li>LI 2</li>
  <li>LI 3</li>
  <li>LI 4</li>
  <li>LI 5</li>
</ul>
```

This snippet should probably works if `transform` was set as an “additive property”:

```css
li ~ li {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LI 1</li>
  <li>LI 2</li>
  <li>LI 3</li>
  <li>LI 4</li>
  <li>LI 5</li>
</ul>
```

I know how it can be done by reordering the HTML (but elements won't be siblings anymore) or by using some JavaScript but…
Isn't there any trick that makes the above possible only with CSS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: only transform is needed here, or it can be something generic?

Comment: Hey @TemaniAfif ! You're always there... :) In fact, I chose `transform` because we can do a lot of things with it. And if it can be applied to `transform`, why not on another property?

Comment: with transform we may approximate what you want using a more generic transform combined with some perspective, etc (some hacks ..) as I don't think what you want is possible, the challenge is somehow the same as you previous question. There is no way to express values between sibling elements, only nested element may have some relation.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, maybe I'm trying to push the limits. :)

Comment: @TakitIsy is it allowed to use js or you want this to be only with css selectors, Am not sure if this can be solved with just plain css selectors

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The only way i would know of is to give every li a class, but that would just shift the problem.

However there are loops in CSS Preprocessors like less or Sass, where you could iterate though the list and make the transform value smaller or bigger.

[Less Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-loops-feature)